# Appropriate site for game-dev question about object-oriented optimization?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about optimizing the creation of objects (by using a pool to recycle objects instead of actual creation) in a game that I intend to run on Android. I use LibGDX for the game but I don't think that my question is dependent on that framework. Should I ask here (Programmers) or on Game Development?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are Design Review questions on-topic?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6502/are-design-review-questions-on-topic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the surface, it seems like it's perfectly on-topic here on Programmers. It's ultimately a design question to optimize your design for performance.